# When downloading AppLovin-SDK from Mac CocoaPod causes error and fails

Tags: macos, github, cocoapods, applovin

[image: error message]

So, this is what happens even if I entered correct Github UserName (or ID) and Password.

I have tried it with, name, UserName, Email ID but it all fails.

How can I get through this authentication step? plz help!!

Answer (score 0):

> entered correct Github UserName (or ID) and Password.

That the point of the error message. GitHub no longer accept passwords (since [Aug. 2021](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-08-12-git-password-authentication-is-shutting-down/)), only PAT ([Personal Access Token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token))

If you enter your token as a password, it would work.

you can also check your `git config --global credential.helper` is set to `manager` the Microsoft cross-platform [GCM (Git Credential Manager)](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager)).
That way, you will cache said credentials (username+token), and won't have to enter them again.